# PDF document security vs document restrictions

Tags: pdf, metadata, pdfsharp

What is the difference between pdf document security (when you click the 'Show Details' button  as shown in the image below) and document restrictions summary.

Are they different?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are not different but Document Security dialog present restrictions in more detailed manner. Below is a screenshot for one of my PDFs encrypted with AES 128 bit.

As you can see, Document Properties dialog only shows that printing is allowed whereas Document Security dialog shows that it is allowed to print in high resolution (a PDF document permissions can specify if high or low resolution is allowed to be used while printing).

[image]